# Couchbase 2.0 Java SDK 1.1 - Synchronous Add and Views

Tags: java, sdk, couchbase

**I am trying to create a junit test. Scenario:**

- setUp: I'm adding two json documents to database
- Test: I'm getting those documents using view
- tearDown: I'm removing both objects

**My view:**

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if (doc.type && doc.type == "UserConnection") {
    emit([doc.providerId, doc.providerUserId], doc.userId);
  } 
}
```

**This is how I add those documents to database and make sure that "add" is synchronous:**

```
public boolean add(String key, Object element) {
    String json = gson.toJson(element);
    OperationFuture<Boolean> result = couchbaseClient.add(key, 0, json);
    return result.get();
}
```

**JSON Documents that I'm adding are:**
{"userId":"1","providerId":"test_pId","providerUserId":"test_pUId","type":"UserConnection"}
{"userId":"2","providerId":"test_pId","providerUserId":"test_pUId","type":"UserConnection"}

**This is how I call the view:**

```
View view = couchbaseClient.getView(DESIGN_DOCUMENT_NAME, VIEW_NAME);
Query query = new Query();
query.setKey(ComplexKey.of("test_pId", "test_pUId"));
ViewResponse viewResponse = couchbaseClient.query(view, query);
```

**Problem:**

- Test fails due to invalid number of elements fetched from view.

**My observations:**

- Sometimes tests are passing
- Number of elements that are fetched from view is not consistent(from 0 to 2)
- When I've added those documents to database instead of calling setUp the test passed every time
- Acording to this http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-java-1.1/create-update-docs.html documentation I'm adding those json documents synchronously by calling get() on returned Future object.

**My question:**

- Is there something wrong with how I've approached to fetching data from view just after this data was inserted to DB? Is there any good practise for solving this problem? And can someone explain it to me please what I've did wrong?

Thanks,
Dariusz

Answer (score 1):

In Couchbase 2.0 documents are required to be written to disk before they will show up in a view. There are three ways you can do an operation with the Java SDK. The first is asynchronous which means that you just send the data and at a later time check to make sure that the data was received correctly. If you do an asynchronous operation and then immediately call .get() as you did above then you have created a synchronous operation. When an operation returns success in these two cases above you are only guaranteed that the item has been written into memory. Your test passed sometimes only because you were lucky enough that both items were written to disk before did your query.

The third way to do an operation is with durability requirements and this is the one you want to do for your tests. Durability requirements allow you to say that you want an item to be written to disk or replicated before success is returned to the client. Take a look at the following function.

https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client/blob/1.1.0/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/CouchbaseClient.java#L1293

You will want to use this function and set the PersistedTo parameter to MASTER.

Comment: In addition to the PersistTo to be sure your disk you also need to call the view using stale=false to be sure the index is updated before  returning it to your application. Take a look to: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-writing-stale.html